# Spring- Boot : How to handle timestamp (ie save and get timestamp to and from sql database)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sql-timestamp

I'm developing a spring boot application and i'm having problems in handling `java.sql.timestamp`. When i store the timestamp to database it store the right timestamp but when i fetch the timestamp from database it fetches the timestamp with 5:30 hours of difference. I'm getting wired result, sometimes i get same timestamp as in database and sometimes i'm getting timestamp with 5:30 hours of difference. I even used `@JsonFormat(timezone = "GMT+05:30")` annotation to get the consistent results. But some times it gives different results.

Comment: The best way to handle it is to use `Instant` instead.

Comment: `Instant` is _probably_ what you want, but you haven't stated what you're actually attempting to store (what conceptual thing).  Other than that, what RDBMs are you using, and what's the underlying type in the database?  That's going to have an effect on your results as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to handle all Timezone problems while reading/writing to database in SpringBoot applications.

Use Java8 LocalDateTime instead of Timestamp. Create a converter class like this to match Timestamp in DB and LocalDateTime in your application:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime locDateTime) {
        return (locDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(locDateTime));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp sqlTimestamp) {
        return (sqlTimestamp == null ? null : sqlTimestamp.toLocalDateTime());
    }
}
```

Set your application's default timezone in your main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApplication {
    private static final String ZONE_ID_ISTANBUL = "Europe/Istanbul";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZONE_ID_ISTANBUL));
        System.out.println("Application time zone: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

By setting default time zone, whenever you use LocalDateTime, it will use this timezone as default, therefore even though your database runs in a different timezone with your application, you will run your code in your time zone.

Note that after creating the converter class, you have to use it in your entity as follows:

```
@Column(name = "insert_time", nullable = false)
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter.class)
private LocalDateTime insertTime;
```

Comment: No, (almost certainly) absolutely not.  Most of the major JPA providers - including the Spring-provided one - support the Java 8 date/time types directly, there's no reason to use `java.sql.Timestamp` anymore.  Doing this is also going to cause additional problems down the road; what those are is going to depend on the field used in the database itself, as well as the connection setting and the timezone of the application server.  Which is another thing: the timezone of an application server is (almost) never relevant, and should be left in UTC to avoid coding errors from other libraries.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse can you please explain how to use Java 8 date/time classes directly to match Timestamp in DB without using the converters?

Comment: The **database** doesn't have `java.sql.Timestamp`, so you don't need a converter for that.  It _might_ have a type labeled as "timestamp", but what that means varies from date-time-without-timezone to some-internal-representation-that-you-shouldn't-use.  Springs's provider will just read whatever the native database type is into the given Java 8 type, without the detour.  What specific type is needed depends on the database and type chosen, which we don't have in the original post.